# Python cx_Oracle in/out variables for callproc

Tags: python, python-2.7, procedure, cx-oracle

I have an oracle procedure that is supposed to return a chunk of json.

The procedure has 4 paramaters

input is an ID value
output json CLOB
output some message in json format CLOB
output if success or failure varchar2

so in my code I have done the following just to test if I can successfully call and return it

```
ConnectionString = 'someconnection.connection'
con = cx_Oracle.connect(ConnectionString)
cur = con.cursor()

ID = '51858645'
json_out = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)
message = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)
status = cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
oracle_return = cur.callproc('project.getsomejson',[ID,json_out,message,status])
```

However, it fails and returns

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'getsomejson'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

This is the procedure definition

```
procedure callOracle(json_in clob,json_out out clob,message out clob,status out varchar2)
```

This is calling an oracle 12c db
I'm really not familiar at all with calling procedures in python. Typically I callfunc with the stored type and just get a return

Comment: Give us the actual PL/SQL procedure definition so we don't have to guess what the mismatch might be.  Also give us the cx_Oracle version and the Oracle client library and Oracle DB versions because behavior has changed throughout the releases.

Comment: @ChristopherJones added at bottom

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is expecting

CLOB, CLOB, CLOB, VARCHAR2

but you are passing

VARCHAR2, CLOB, CLOB, VARCHAR2

The name you gave (callOracle) also doesn't match what you are calling in Python (project.getsomejson). Perhaps verify that you have the right procedure signature? Assuming it is correct, though, you'll need to change the first one to be a CLOB as well or change the stored procedure to accept VARCHAR2. Something like this should do it:

```py
json_in = conn.createlob(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_CLOB)
json_in.write("51858645")
json_out_var = cur.var(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_CLOB)
message_var = cur.var(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_CLOB)
status_var = cur.var(str)
cur.callproc(json_in, json_out, message, status)
```